# IndexError: list assignment index out of range, deletion

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range, del

I am trying to make a program that loops through a list of `headlines` and remove items that have similar headlines in the rest of the list.

```
# Loop through headlines and remove over 50% similar ones
headlines = listHeadlines()
# headlines.append('Our plan is working says Hunt, as Bank raises interest rate to 5.25%')
print(len(headlines), headlines)
headlines_copy = list(headlines)
for headline in headlines_copy:
    for h in headlines_copy:
        if h == headline:
            pass
        elif areStringsSimilar(h, headline):
            del headlines[headlines_copy.index(headline)]
            break  # Exit this loop and move back to other because headline has been deleted from list.

print(len(headlines), headlines)
```

The first `print(len(headlines), headlines)` works and prints `1248 [list]` but then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[path]/main.py", line 95, in <module>
    del headlines[headlines_copy.index(headline)]
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: why not `list(set(headlines))` ?  use while loop for deletion from a list

Comment: If your list is `["a", "b", "c"]`, where `areStringsSimilar("a", "b") == true`, do you expect the result to be `["a","c"]`, `["b", "c"]` or `["c"]`?

Comment: @sahasrara62: They are using `areStringsSimilar()` to determine similarness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not append the headlines you want to keep rather than deleting the headlines you don't want:

```py
headlines = listHeadlines()
deduplicated = []
for candidate in headlines:
    if not any(map(lambda kept: areStringsSimilar(candidate, kept), deduplicated)):
        deduplicated.append(candidate)
print(deduplicated)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to append headlines to a new list, because I didn't know how to without appending the same headline multiple times as I use a nested loop. Your solution seems to have avoided this, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

> ##### `list.remove(x)`
>
> Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

So instead of             `del headlines[headlines_copy.index(headline)]`, just do `headlines.remove(headline)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
index = 0
headlines = listHeadlines()
print(len(headlines), headlines)
while index < len(headlines):
    for i, h in enumerate(headlines):
        if i == index:
            pass
        elif areStringsSimilar(h, headline):
            del headlines[i]
            index -= 1
            break  
    else:
       index += 1

print(len(headlines), headlines)
```